# Bottom part of spherical objects print problematic

Tags: print-quality, flyingbear-ghost-4

I got a Flyingbear Ghost 4 and using Cura. It is doing fine until I have to print spheric things. I'm using a high density material that needs to be at 210 °C and slower print speed. I also built a top and a door for my printer so it's partly enclosed at 90 %

An easy example of what I got is a sphere object.

The lower half is messy with uneven surface, lot of visible strings marks at firsts layers. While upper part is just perfect. I tried to to work around it multiple times but can't find any worthy info on internet. Tried to slowing down the printing speed by max 50 %, thicker shell, nothing seems to work.

Here a Lapras I did to my son to show you.
[image]

Settings:

- Fan_Speed : 100 % (it's off for the first layer)
- LayerHeight : 0.1 mm
- Bed_Temperature : 60 °C
- Nozzle_Temperature : 210 °C
- Nozzle_size : 0.4 mm
- Shell_Thickness : 1.6 mm (so 4 passes)
- Printing_speed : 45 mm/sec (max moving speed for this printer is 150 mm/sec,
  default printing speed is 60 mm/sec)
- Support_type : Everywhere
- Support_Min_Angle : 59°

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Please add a photo to show the problem otherwise the question may end up being closed for insufficient amount of information to solve the problem.

Comment: This is a potential duplicate question of [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13915/3d-printed-sphere-how-to-remove-roughness).