# Help With Bottom of Sphere Coming off With Supports

Tags: support-structures

I printed this on an Ender 3 S1 Pro at 215˚C with a 20% infill (actually 5 were printed at once).  The print bed was leveled prior to print.[image: The sphere with its bottom s]

When I tried to remove the supports, they took the bottom of the sphere off with them.

How typical is this, and what parameters can I change to have the best chance of a successful print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen question [3D Printed Sphere, How to Remove Roughness](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13915/3d-printed-sphere-how-to-remove-roughness)? Although the question is centered around the roughness, not the supports, the answers hint to a solution for this question.

If you look at the answers, you see that in case you have have unsupported perimeters (see image below), they sag out (as seen in your print where the lower perimeters of the sphere are not perectly round) and may fuse with the support causing the support and the perimiters (walls) to bond quite well.

Furthermore, if you use too few perimeters and a low infill percentage, the print object will become weak and have an increased change that removing the print from the plate or the support from the print cause the print to break.

[image]

<sub>Picture credits to [Trish](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/13918/), this is 180° rotated</sub>

Comment: Thank you, Oscar, pretty much exactly the information I needed to see to guide me in the right direction.  Unfortunately, I can't upvote your answer since I don't have enough reputation.